# Accessing the index/row/column from a selected cell in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm supposed to be turning an excel spreadsheet with nontrivial functions into a web application. I have decided to work with Pandas, and I'm wondering what the best way to approach this is.

One of the things I need to do is allow people to input a certain number (we'll call this `lot_number`) and access other values in the same row.

For example, if `lot_number = 3`, `address_value` in a different column will be 555 Something Street. All of the `lot_numbers` and `address_value` entries are different.

My question is this: how can I access `address_value` using pandas depending on `lot_number`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

Use iloc. Example as follows:

```
df.iloc[row, column] # accepts ints
```

This will give you access to that column and row.

**Updated**

So we find the row index and then do my original suggestion and get the entire row.

```
row = df.loc[df['address_value']==lot_number].index[0]
df.iloc[row]
```

Comment: I don't think this appropriately addresses the question. The row will need to come from whatever row lot_number is in.

Comment: Sorry about that - See how you get on with the new updated

Comment: This seems like it may work, but it looks like it's returning too much data. Hang on a sec and let me check it out

Comment: I think this is close. I'm getting this error now. IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Same here. Try [row, :]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155664/discussion-between-vipertherapper-and-adders).

Comment: I just converted that row/column into a dictionary and had a much easier time working with that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

By using `lookup`

```
df.lookup(df[df['lot_number']==3].index,['address_value'])

Out[211]: array(['foo'], dtype=object)
```

Data input

```
df
Out[212]: 
  address_value  lot_number
0           foo           3
1           bar           2
2          blah           1

df = pd.DataFrame({'lot_number':[3,2,1], 'address_value':['foo','bar','blah']})
```

EDIT

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lot_number':[3,3,1], 'address_value':['foo','bar','blah']})

df.lookup(df[df['lot_number']==3].index,['address_value']*len(df[df['lot_number']==3].index))

Out[223]: array(['foo', 'bar'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Hi Wen. This looks perfect and works when I run your example, but with the csv I'm importing, I get this error.                                                    
       ValueError: Row labels must have same size as column labels .                       Any idea why?

Comment: @vipertherapper you have duplicated in columns `['lot_number']`

Comment: @vipertherapper updated , BTW , you reach 15 reputation , you can upvote , and also accept  the answer  you like :)

Comment: Wen has enough rep. Help me out haha

Comment: Yes, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can figure this out. I'm still getting an error though.   File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx"....
KeyError: 'lot_number'

Comment: @vipertherapper maybe you have blank like `lot_number `